# split a link with php / preg_split

Tags: php, string

i have a link with the following (varying) structure:

http://website.com/category/product/abc12345

the category- and the productname vary concerning their length, but the id (abc12345) is always located after the last "/" and is about 6-8 chars long.

i tried to extract the link with the following code:

```
preg_split('/[/]/', $val, $arr);
$narr[] = end($arr);
```

with val being the link and arr being the array, the result should be pasted in.
narr is the array i want to save to a file later, so it doesn't really matter here. unfortunately, my results are always empty when i try it this way.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract from the url? `category/product/abc12345`?

Comment: If you're just wanting to parse the string(URL) out to an array of strings...you might try the php function explode(). Then you could do something like $myItem = "explode('/', urlStringvar)[4]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go for:

```
$urlParts = parse_url($myUrl);
$parts = explode('/', $urlParts['path']);
$productId = array_pop($parts);
```

That way, you have no problems with anchors (#content) or query parameters (?id=123)

Comment: this extracts the following: /category/products/abc12345

Comment: what do i use instead of 'path'?

Comment: `path` is the array index.

See the [manual on parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Under the following conditions:

- The product (abc12345) is always at the end of the url
- No querystrings/params

Try the following regular expression:

```
preg_match('/\/([\w]+)\/?$/', $val, $arr);
$product = $arr[1];
```

Comment: there's a '/' to much somewhere

Comment: Oh, right. I was testing this using the Chrome inspector. My mistake, although what seems to be missing are quotes?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `preg_match`:

```
if (preg_match('#.*/(.*)#', $val, $match)) {
    $result = $match[1];
}
```

You could also use something as simple as `strrpos` and `substr`:

```
$result = substr($val, strrpos($val, '/') + 1);
```